# no GAE Backends has been created with valid backends.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When I check my application dashboard "backends" section , Google says that no Google App Engine backends has been created , despite that I created valid backends.xml. 
Where is the problem?
On local dev server everything is ok . Backends work fine with this backends.xml on the local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that to configure your app's backends, it's subtly different commands than configuring the rest of your app. When I forgot... *ahem*, I mean, if *you* forget and just use the usual app config commands, it updates most of your app, but leaves the backends alone. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Commands

Answer (score 1):

Larry is right. To be exact for novices like me. Here is the command that will do the trick.

```
appcfg backends update <path-to-war-directory>
```